# Zend Framework AjaxContext filters the results and Decorators not removable

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

Ok, since this problem has 2 parts, it will be easier to explain them together. So here goes:

1. I am trying to remove the default decorators from these elements, since I am using a little different way of styling them. But no matter what i do, the DtDDWrapper still shows up. If I try to remove all of the decorators, all of the fields below disappear.

   ```
   public function newfieldAction() {


   $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
   $ajaxContext->addActionContext('newfield', 'html')->initContext();


   $id = $this->_getParam('id', null);
   $id1=$id+1;
   $id2=$id+2;


   $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("newTitle$id1");
   $element->setOptions(array('escape'=>false));
   $element->setRequired(true)->setLabel('Vertība')->removeDecorator('label');
   $tinyelement=new Zend_Form_Element_Text("newName$id");
   $tinyelement->setRequired(true)->setOptions(array('escape'=>false))->setLabel('Vertība')->removeDecorator('label');
   $textarea_element = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea("newText$id2");
   $textarea_element->setRequired(true)->setOptions(array('escape'=>false))->setLabel('Vertība')->removeDecorator('label');


   $this->view->descriptionField = "<td>".$textarea_element->__toString()."</td>";
   $this->view->titleField = $element->__toString();
   $this->view->field = $tinyelement->__toString();
   $this->view->id=$id;
   }
   ```
2. The context view script seams to trim my code in one way or another. When I try to put a `<td>` or a `<table>` tag in the view script, it just skips the tags. Is there a way to stop this escaping from happening? My view script:

   ```
   <tr class="element<php echo $this->id; ?>">
   asdfasdfasdfasd
   <td><?php echo $this->field ?></td>
   <td><php echo $this->titleField ?></td>
   <td><php echo $this->descriptionField ?></td>


   <td><a class="remove-element" rel="<php echo $this->id ?>">remove</a></td>


   </tr>
   ```

P.S. the code formatting system is barfing at me, could someone please help me with the formatting of the code?

Comment: Think the code formatting issues have to do with your ordered list. Had to double indent the code sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Decorators

At a minimum, you need to set the `ViewHelper` decorator. This is the one that renders the element itself.

To disable the default decorators, the easiest way to do so is via the element constructor by either setting the decorators via the `decorators` option or setting the `disableLoadDefaultDecorators` option to false (but you will still need to set decorators later). For example

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("newTitle$id1", array(
    'decorators' => array('ViewHelper')
));
```

---

## View Script

You will need to elaborate what you mean by "skips the tags". Apart from that `asdfasdfasdfasd` out of place string in your markup, I can't see any problem.

This may also be effected by where in the DOM you're loading / placing the AJAX context. Loading it in the wrong place, creating invalid markup may make it appear to not display correctly.

Comment: Ok, as far as the view goes, you're absolutely right. I just took a look at the Firebug console, and the response was 'A' ok. And for the decorators as well. You must be genious! And I struggled with this thing for ages. Darnit! :)

Comment: @Janis Just noticed you also have a nested `<td>` element in your `descriptionField` string.